# SVG animation flying line with gradient color like nextjs.org website

Tags: svg

Please help me understand how these animations are implemented. I can't figure out how to implement a flying line with a gradient color?. (on website nextjs.org)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obvDq.jpg)

I could only implement a flying line but I can't implement a gradient color.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a discussion forum. We can help if you have specific issues with your code. So please share what you already got and explain what the problem is. Suggestion for an article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.